# Phonegap - implementing share via functionality for pictures

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I'm looking to create a phonegap application and I was wondering if there were any examples of someone enabling their application to appear in the "share via" menu on android. I've been looking around and can't seem to find any examples of how this interacts with the application. From what I've seen of phonegap so far I'd imagine there would have to be a plugin to detect if any parameters are being passed to the app. If so then redirect to a different page? If anyone could assist me with this issue I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks !

Comment: I think I found a solution with the phonegap web intent plugin.